# Combine constraints and data transformers

Tags: forms, validation, symfony, transformation

I would like to do something looking like what is done in [How to use Data Transformers](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html) tutorial. But I would like to add a process and I can't find any example.

In the symfony tutorial, data transformation is about changing an issue number to an `Issue` object. This is done in the `reverseTransform()` function of `IssueToNumberTransformer`

```
public function reverseTransform($number)
{
    if (!$number) {
        return null;
    }

    $issue = $this->om
        ->getRepository('AcmeTaskBundle:Issue')
        ->findOneBy(array('number' => $number))
    ;

    if (null === $issue) {
        throw new TransformationFailedException(sprintf(
            'An issue with number "%s" does not exist!',
            $number
        ));
    }

    return $issue;
}
```

We can see that if an invalid  issue number is provided, transformation will failed and the function throw a `TransformationFailedException`. As a result, the form as an error with message "This value is not valid". It would be great to personalize this message.

The data transformation process is executed before any validation (with constraints applied to the field), so I can't find a way to validate the issue number before trying to transform it.

As another example of why I have to validate before transformation is I use the MongoDB Document Manager to convert the "Issue mongo id" to an Issue (the form is used by a REST API server, that's why I receive an id). So :

```
public function reverseTransform($id)
{
    if (!$number) {
        return null;
    }

    $issue = $this->dm
        ->getRepository('AcmeTaskBundle:Issue')
        ->find(new \MongoId($id))
    ;

    if (null === $issue) {
        throw new TransformationFailedException(sprintf(
            'An issue with number "%s" does not exist!',
            $number
        ));
    }

    return $issue;
}
```

Here, if the id I receive in my API form is not formated as correct MongoID, client will receive a 500. So I want to check, before transformation if received id is correct, because if it's not, transformation will throw a fatal error. And if I manage all cases in my transformation, like checking if $id is correct, it's like I'm doing validation in the transformer and it's not correct.

My question is : is there a way to apply constraints before the data transformation ? or is there a way to add a digest constraintViolation on the form when transformation failed ?

Comment: have you tried surrounding, with a try/catch block, when doing the `$form->handleRequest` ?

Comment: The try/catch will not work since the form component will swallow any DataTransformer errors.  Check the code.  The thing is, transforming is for transforming and not validation.  So don't try to validate during the transform operation.  You need to check for a null issue in your validation.

Comment: I was wrong telling that my response is a 500. I have a form error just telling "This value is not valid". What do you mean by "You need to check for a null issue in your validation" ?

Comment: I edited the question adding a second example to show why I have to validate data before transformation

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is like a workaround, however I suggest writing the class that represents "an invalid issue" to personalize error.

```
class InvalidIssue extends Issue
{
    public $message = 'This issue is invalid';

    public function __construct($message = null)
    {
        if (null !== $message) {
            $this->message = $message;
        }
    }
}
```

and in the transformer, if given value is invalid, return `InvalidIssue` object instead of throwing an exception.

```
public function reverseTransform($id)
{
    if (!$number) {
        return null;
    }

    $issue = $this->dm
        ->getRepository('AcmeTaskBundle:Issue')
        ->find(new \MongoId($id))
    ;

    if (null === $issue) {
        return new InvalidIssue(sprintf(
            'An issue with number "%s" does not exist!',
            $number
        ));
    }

    return $issue;
}
```

then, add validator onto your model.

```
/** Assert\Callback("callback"="validateIssueIsValid") */
class YourModel
{
    protected $issue;

    public function setIssue(Issue $issue)
    {
        $this->issue = $issue;
    }

    public function validateIssueIsValid(ExecutionContextInterface $context)
    {
        if ($this->issue instanceof InvalidIssue) {
            $context->addViolationAt('issue', $this->issue->message, array());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I validated the answer, this is a pretty good idea... Hoping that symfony will one day upgrade its validation system to support this kind of situation. Thank you

Comment: Nice solution!  I don't understand how this is overlooked by symfony.