# Change data of form field after submit

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I have Message entity with field 'url'. And MessageType form. User can type different urls in 'url' but only host is persisted to the database. I need to use Symfony2 Form Event. So I try to implement it in next code:

```
class MessageType extends AbstractType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('url'); 

         $builder->addEventListener(
                FormEvents::SUBMIT,
                function(FormEvent $event) {
                    $form = $event->getForm();

                    $data = $event->getData();
                    $url = $data->getUrl();
                    $form->setData(parse_url($url), PHP_URL_HOST);
                }
        );
    }
}
```

I  get the following notice:

> "Notice: Array to string conversion"

What does this mean?

My Message entity has method `__toString()`:

```
public function __toString()
{
    return $this->getUrl();
}
```

Thank You

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try using a [Data Transformer](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html) which is designed for this purpose.  For example:

```
namespace Vendor\MyBundle\Form\DataTransformer;

use Symfony\Component\Form\DataTransformerInterface;

class HostFromUrlTransformer implements DataTransformerInterface
{
    public function transform($host)
    {
        return ($host === null) ? "" : $host;
    }

    public function reverseTransform($url)
    {
        return parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);
    }
}
```

Then implementing in the form:

```
use Vendor\MyBundle\Form\DataTransformer\HostFromUrlTransformer;

class MessageType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add(
            $builder->create('url')
                ->addModelTransformer(new HostFromUrlTransformer())
        );
    }
}
```

This method definitely has its faults, however.  You would not be able to add an `Assert\URL` on the entity because the validation happens after the transformations, and the just having the host portion would no longer make it valid.  You could work around this by passing in the Symfony validator to your data transformer, then validating the $url against `Assert\Url` similar to a method here: [Combine constraints and data transformers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21140233/combine-constraints-and-data-transformers) , but that also feels a bit hacky.

An easier solution than all of this would simply be to update the `setUrl($url)` method in your entity to something like this:

```
public function setUrl($url)
{
    $host = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);
    $this->url = $host ?: $url;
}
```

So in that case, if you are passing in a URL it saves as just the $host, and if you are using setUrl() and it's already transformed, it would just keep the already-existing value.

Even better still, you could simply save the full URL they send you, which would allow you to maintain the `@Assert\URL` validation, and then add the following two functions:

```
public function getHost()
{
    return parse_url($this->url, PHP_URL_HOST);
}

public function __toString()
{
    return $this->getHost();
}
```

The above allows you to keep all data that was saved, and changes the work of parsing the URL to be done by your application, rather than try to parse out in the database layer.  The `__toString()` method will always return the host, and you still have access to full URL that was passed in if you need it.  You could even get rid of the `getHost()` function above.

If you want to use a FormEvent, you are on the right track but the code is a little off.  See http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/form/form_events.html#b-the-formevents-submit-event for more details.

```
$builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, function (FormEvent $event)
{
    $data = $event->getData();
    $data['url'] = parse_url($data['url'], PHP_URL_HOST);

    $event->setData($data);

    // this one-liner might also work in place of the 3 lines above
    $event->setData('url', parse_url($event->getData('url'), PHP_URL_HOST));
});
```

Comment: Thank you! It works! I've also imlemented PrePersist event for this task. But I wanna to understand next. How can I change form data before persist and then persist result into database using FormEvents. Can U help me?

Comment: Which method of mine above did you try?  PrePersist would also work, but keep in mind that would just be for the initial insert and not any updates.  What task are you trying to do in PrePersist?  You mean doing it through that instead of the other methods I have above?

Comment: Excuse I haven't written before. I mean imlementation one of the FormEvents in code public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface `$builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('url'); 

         $builder->addEventListener( TO DO )`

Comment: So is there something else you need to ask?  If you use any of my methods (or a PrePersist) above then you don't need a form event.

Comment: I undestand it. But it is important for me to understand how can I imlement task wit FormEvent)))

Comment: Is there a reason why you *have* to use a form event?  My first suggestion using a DataTransformer is designed for the exact purpose you are looking for and is the preferred method over a FormEvent.

Comment: I'm new in Symfony. So I try to understand and implement according to the implementations of Symfony2 components. I understand that you code is great. And thank you for helping. But also I want to understand how I can use FormEevent for real example (not only theory from symfony documentation)

Comment: I understand.  I added updated code at the bottom of my post which should accomplish what you are looking to do.  I also gave 2 different ways of changing the data...they might both work but I haven't actually tested it, so try both out yourself and see if they work.  Also you can probably use the `SUBMIT` or `POST_SUBMIT` events instead of `PRE_SUBMIT` but for this simpler case it shouldn't make too much of a difference.

Comment: Thank You! My mistake was in imlementation of appropriate event. So can I ask you help me understand another features of Symfony? If you do not mind? please add me in skype (john.home64) or ICQ (463201357)

Answer (score 1):

According to PHP doc for `parse_url()` :

> If the component parameter is omitted, an associative array is
>   returned.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

Looks like you're not properly passing the component parameter in your code, there's a misplaced parenthesis :

```
$form->setData(parse_url($url), PHP_URL_HOST);
```

Should be:

```
$form->setData(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST));
```

---

Also, I'm not sure you're setting the data like you should but I may be wrong. This is how I think you should do it :

```
$form->get('url')->setData(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST));
```

---

Here's the complete (and untested) code I was thinking of :

```
class MessageType extends AbstractType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('url'); 

         $builder->addEventListener(
                FormEvents::SUBMIT,
                function(FormEvent $event) {
                    $form = $event->getForm(); // FormInterface
                    $data = $event->getData(); 
                    $url = $data->getUrl();
                    $host = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);
                    if ($host)
                        $form->get('url')->setData($host);
                }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Great catch on the parameters, I missed it the first time I looked at the question.

Comment: @paulgv If ot is not difficult for you, please, demonstrate examle of code how can I change data of form. I try different ways, but full url is persisted to my database

Comment: I mean that paulgv noticed that you were passing the parameters wrong.  You were passing `PHP_URL_HOST` to the `setData()` function rather than the `parse_url` function, and he also noticed you were missing defining which parameter to modify.

Comment: @Jason Roman Can you help me to understand how I can modify uri field before persist to database? I read symfony cookbook about form event, But I can't imlement it for my task...

Comment: I would use a data transformer.  I'll post an example for that shortly.

Comment: @Antin did you try the last line of code in my answer ? I think it should do what you want. Jason Roman, yeah that thing with parenthesis happens to me all the time with Sublime Text :D

Comment: @paulgv I cannot understand how to use your recommenation(((. Please, help me. There is no method 'get' for FormEvent. I tried to refactor my code according Ur recommendation and got next `$builder->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::SUBMIT,
            function(FormEvent $event) {
                $data = $event->getData()->get('url');
                $url = parse_url($data, PHP_URL_HOST);
                $event->setData($url);`

Comment: @paulgv And I got next mistake `Attempted to call method "get" on class "Ens\JobeetBundle\Entity\Job". Did you mean to call e.g..."getUrl"` So I refactor my code according it and got next `$builder->addEventListener(
            FormEvents::SUBMIT,
            function(FormEvent $event) {
                $data = $event->getData()->getUrl();
                $url = parse_url($data, PHP_URL_HOST);
                $event->setData($url);}`

Comment: @paulgv But event didn't change data of $url. And entire url (not host) persisted to my database. So can you explain how I have to use Ur code? Thanks

Comment: You're right, there is no method `get` in `FormEvent` but there is in `FormInterface` : http://api.symfony.com/2.5/Symfony/Component/Form/FormInterface.html#method_get since you called method `getForm` on your `FormEvent`, you should actually have a `FormInterface` in `$form`. I'm really just reading the documentation, I haven't tested any of this. You might want to try Jason's suggestion, looks like he's got a better idea of what you should be doing. Anyways, I'll edit my answer with the entire `buildForm` function so you know what I thought you should try.

Comment: @paulgv Thank's for help! I try to imlement Ur code. But...get mistake "You cannot change the data of a submitted form." Have an idea how to correct code? (I try Jason's recommendation and its work. I also imlement PrePersist event to resolove this task. But I also wanna to implement changing data from form before persisting using FormEvents!)