# Datatransformer and json validation in symfony2 form

Tags: json, validation, symfony

I'm building a Rest API and I receive a json_encoded string from the clients. 
I want this string to be decoded before saving my entity, because it's going into a `jsonb` field in PostgreSQL.

The behavior I want is :

1. Validate that the string is valid json, if not, add a violation in the form via a custom validator
2. Automatically decode the string and set the json object in the entity property

I've tried two different strategies

1. In the entity `setMetadata($value) method`, if `$value` is a `string`, I decode it
2. I created a DataTransformer that `json_decode` the value received in the form

But both these solutions don't work because the custom validator I created is called after, and it calls directly `$lesson->getMetadata()`. Since the value has already been decoded (either in the `setMetadata() method` or in the `DataTransformer`, the `validator` receive either a `json object` or `null`. So I can't add a violation to the form, since I have no way to know if the value received was actually null, or if the string was malformed.

Here is the lesson entity:

```
class Lesson extends BaseContent
{
    […]

    /**
     * @var jsonb
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="metadata", type="jsonb", nullable=true)
     * @KreactiveAssert\Json
     */
    private $metadata;
    […]
}
```

Here is the custom validator:

```
class JsonValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{
    public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint)
    {
        if ($value && !json_decode($value)) {
            $this->context->addViolation($constraint->message, array('%string%' => $value));
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the DataTransformer:

```
class StringToJsonTransformer implements DataTransformerInterface
{
    /**
     * Transform a json object to a string
     * @param  Json|null $json
     * @return String
     */
    public function transform($json)
    {
        if (null === $json) {
            return "";
        }

        return json_encode($json);
    }

    /**
     * Transform a string to a json object
     * @param  String $string
     * @return Object
     */
    public function reverseTransform($string)
    {
        if (!$string) {
            return null;
        }

        throw new TransformationFailedException('error transforming');

        return json_decode($string);
    }
}
```

Is there any way I can validate the input data in the form, and then set the metadata as a json object?

Comment: first thought - for json validation you might be better off not testing the return value of `json_decode()` and instead use [`json_last_error()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php) to validate the result of the operation and [`json_last_error_msg()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error-msg.php) to build your error string if appropriate.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've found this (I don't know how come I didn't find it earlier):

[Combine constraints and data transformers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21140233/combine-constraints-and-data-transformers)

I'm going to make an ugly workaround as suggested, even though I don't like that solution.

```
<?php

class StringToJsonTransformer implements DataTransformerInterface
{

    /**
     * Transform a string to a json object
     * @param  String $string
     * @return Object
     */
    public function reverseTransform($string)
    {
        if (!$string) {
            return null;
        }


        /*
         * UGLY WORKAROUND
         * we return -1 if the json_decode fail
         * so the validator can add a violation in the form telling
         * the json string was not valid
         * If we don't do this, the validator will receive either
         * null or a json object. In case of null, there is no way to
         * tell if the client sent null, or if the decoding failed
         */
        $value = json_decode($string);

        return $value ? $value : -1;
    }
}
```

I'm still not sure if I'm going to return -1 or something else. In the custom validator, I get an error if I try to compare a jsonObject with -1 (which is normal).