# symfony2 data transformer and asserts

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I have a symfony2 entity linked to a user entity. The user only submits a users username, not the users ID. So I created a Data Transformer, which works perfectly.

Due to the fact that a username can only have exactly 8 characters I wanted to create a custom error message by adding a `Assert\Length` to the field. But that does not work, because the form only accepts a user-object, not a string.

So I tried by creating a `Assert\Callback` for the user-field, but that also didn't work for me because I wasn't able to access the submitted value in the Callback / ExecutionContextInterface to test the submitted string (not an object, because wrong length means no user can be found!)

Neither did it work to use the DataTransformer because the thrown `TransformationFailedException` won't be translated to custom error messages for the user - and that's what I wanted to achieve!

Has anybody an idea how to do this?

Thank you very much!

Martin

Comment: Have you tried adding a validator directly to the form field?  You can do this with the constraints option.

Comment: No, that does not work either. Maybe I forgot to mention that I use the DataTransformer as a service, but the additional constraints at the form field are not called, it just shows the transformation error because no user entity was found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to achieve what I wanted to do was to use the method answered in [Combine constraints and data transformers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21140233/combine-constraints-and-data-transformers). Hope that helps others too!