# How to disable one transformer validation error "dynamically" in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, symfony2-forms, symfony-validator

I have a form with many fields and validation groups, these fields contain some view data transformers too.

I need suppress the validation form partially ([Groups based on the Submitted Data](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#groups-based-on-the-submitted-data)):

```
use AppBundle\Entity\Client;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

// ...
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'validation_groups' => function (FormInterface $form) {
            $data = $form->getData();

            if (Client::TYPE_PERSON == $data->getType()) {
                return array('person');
            }

            return array('company');
        },
    ));
}
```

When you do that, the form will execute the basic integrity checks ([Disabling Validation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#disabling-validation)) and the validation errors that coming from the transformers were still thrown ([Creating the Transformer](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html#creating-the-transformer)).

Use the `POST_SUBMIT` event and preventing the [ValidationListener](http://api.symfony.com/3.0/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Validator/EventListener/ValidationListener.html) from being called ([Suppressing Form Validation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#suppressing-form-validation)):

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT, function (FormEvent $event) {
        $event->stopPropagation();
    }, 900); // Always set a higher priority than ValidationListener

    // ...
}
```

It is not a solution for me, since accidentally it disables something more than just the form validation.

The question is: **How to disable one transformer validation error "dynamically"?**

**Example:**

I have a form field `RepeatedType` belonging to `person` validation group and contains a view transformer ([RepeatedType](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Core/Type/RepeatedType.php#L35)), this transformer throws an exception when the values in the array aren't the same ([ValueToDuplicatesTransformer](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Core/DataTransformer/ValueToDuplicatesTransformer.php#L69)).

So, even when validation group is `company`, the form shows errors belong to `RepeatedType` field coming from transformers.

The question here is: **How to disable the `ValueToDuplicatesTransformer` errors when validation group is not `person`?**

Comment: Could you explain *why* you're trying to do it?

Comment: How about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21140233/combine-constraints-and-data-transformers

Comment: Thanks for the link, BUT It's not my case, the transformer never turned off and it's not validated by groups.

Comment: I just saw your [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/18109), as recommended in [*What should I do if no one answers my question?*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/no-one-answers), you can start a bounty, it will draw attention to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the `buildForm` misses the code related to adding the fields I assume:

1. you don't relate the form to an Entity via `data_class` directly, but set values in your controller
2. the `repeated` type has `required => true` as an option and is there to validate a password
3. the `$data` that is passed to the formbuilder contains a value for the `repeated` field.

The problem basically is that validation is triggered. If there is any data, then the type will always do it's basic validations (the repeated field should have the same value twice).

What you should do to solve this is do not pass the value to `$data` in the first place, and make sure `required => false` for the repeated field. Your form will only do the group validation *after that*, as you already explained.

Maybe the most robust solution is even different, and would it be best to make two `FormTypes` instead of using the `groups`. This will remove most of the complexity you describe in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really deactivate errors from a DataTransformer, these errors are added by [FormValidator](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/v3.0.3/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Validator/Constraints/FormValidator.php#L98-L103) and this behavior is not customizable. This is quite logical since transformation errors leads to the model data being in a broken state.

What I would do in this case is use 2 field instead of a repeated field with the second one with `mapped => false` and an event listener that add the error manually when needed.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm wrong, but the validation group is not a right tool to solve the problem at all. The dependency of validation rules you want to solve is based on data, while the validation group is not about it, it's about the same data being validating differently depending on context.

If you want to apply some rules only for person (or, the opposite, only for company), I would rather implement custom checking in Client Entity

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

class Client {
....
/**
* @Assert\IsTrue(message="Person should have a valid Title")
*/
public function isPersonTitleValid()
{
  return $this->type != Client::TYPE_PERSON || $this->isTitleValid();
}

public function isTitleValid()
{
  // Here implement your validation applicable only for person;
}
```